# how to change the width of the dropdown List in asp.net dropdownlist control

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

how to change the width of the dropdown List in asp.net dropdownlist control?

What i mean here is not the textbox like control but the the list displaying the items after clicking the dropdown button on the right side?

Is this possible in asp.net dropdownlist control?

Comment: you mean it is a custom control which looks like dropdownlist? or normal dropdownlist?

Comment: the normal dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't change the width of displaying list items as this is default behaviour, but if you realy want like that, you can make your custom dropdown control

Comment: can you give me a link/resource to implement a custom dropdown control?